# Integral step explanation

Tags: integration

I'm calculating the electric field of a linear charge distribution but feeling stuck with an integration step.

$$
\int_0^a \frac{1}{(y-x)^2} dx = \frac{1}{y-a} - \frac{1}{y} 
$$

Is there a simple explanation for this step?

Comment: $\frac1 {y-x}$ is an anti-derivative of $\frac1 {(y-x)^{2}}$.

Comment: Right, this can be shown using substitution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since y is independent of x (or constant with respect to x), we can assume y-x = t as the new variable for integration. Differentiating both sides with respect to x (as y is constant with respect to x $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$) to get :

$\frac{dt}{dx} = -\frac {dx}{dx} = -1 \implies dt = -dx \implies dx = -dt$

Finding limits : when $x = 0, t = y - 0 = y$, and when $x = a, t = y - a$

Thus substituting dx = -dt in the integation and y-x = t we get :

$\int_y^{y-a} \frac{1}{t^2} (-dt)$

Remembering $\frac{1}{t^2} = t^{-2}$ , switching the limits, using the negative sign in -dt, while we know $\int x^n dx = \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1} \forall n \neq -1$ (n is constant with respect to x), we get :

$\int_{y-a}^y t^{-2} dt = \frac {t^{-2+1}}{-2+1}|_{y-a}^y = \frac {t^{-1}}{-1}|_{y-a}^y = -(\frac{1}{y-a} - \frac{1}{y}) = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y-a}$

Comment: The substitution part answered it for me. Thanks

Comment: Then kindly click the green mark beside my answer to show that it was correct